# JasperReport - Open second time without data

Tags: java, caching, jasper-reports

I am developing a Java Swing Application where a report can be generated which contains some variable data and a subreport containing measured values.

Calling the action the first time, the report is generated as expected and shows up correctly in the JasperViewer. But if call the same action a second time, only the static data is shown. Nothing else is generated.

Following code shows the action for the generation of the report:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    try
    {
        InputStream jasperStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(jasperReport);

        MeasurementSubReport measurementReport = new MeasurementSubReport(
            reportService.loadReportColumns(),
            reportService.loadMeasuredValues(),
            reportService.loadStatisticValues());
        JasperReport subreport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(measurementReport.createSubReport());

        Map<String, Object> hm = new HashMap<>();
        hm.put("MEASURE_DATASOURCE", new JREmptyDataSource());
        hm.put("MEASURE_SUBREPORT", subreport);
        hm.put(JRParameter.REPORT_LOCALE, Locale.getDefault());
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperStream, hm, reportDataBean);

        JasperViewer viewer = new JasperViewer(jasperPrint, false);
        viewer.setTitle(BUNDLE.getString("JasperReportAction.viewer.title"));
        viewer.setVisible(true);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ErrorDialog.showError(BUNDLE.getString("JasperReportAction.error.txt"), ex);
    }
}
```

It seems that JasperReports is caching some of the generated code. Is this correct? How can I prevent the caching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have similar code with no problem of cache, for now I will guess some since the `reportDataBean` is not visible in code.

I guees that your `reportDataBean` is a `JRDatasource` if it is [JRRewindableDataSource](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRRewindableDataSource.html) you need to rewind it `moveFirst()`, since it will be at the end after you execute the report first time.

If it is not a `JRRewindableDataSource` you need to re-create it.